# MS Access 2007 autoexec macro alernatives?

Tags: winforms, macros

I'm having an issue with program distributed via Microsoft Access runtime. It runs an autoexec macro at the beginning to run a piece of code. I've done all the security setting and trusted zone settings, but the error seems to crop up on Windows 7 installations.

Ideally, I'd just like to have the code run automatically without the autoexec macro. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is self-certifying the project an option for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read that you could set the starting form with Access options. Then I could run the code from the "OnLoad" event. That might work...

Comment: +1 I generally use a start-up form, but it will not help with security problems, from the point of view of macro security, for 'macro' read 'any code'.